# Pandas to identify first row and column with a date format from xlsx

Tags: excel, pandas

I have 800 xlsx files with similar but non identical structure.

Mission: Using python I want to start reading every xlsx from the row in any column (different columns in different xlsx files) at the first occurrence of a date (either date or datetime format). The headers are then located at this position -1 row.

Any ideas?

Best

Comment: Please include how the dates are formatted ie mm/dd/yyyy if they aren't already in the date time format

Comment: The date and time are either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD 00:00

Comment: The date and time are either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD 00:00

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.